# Не переключаются версии node.js

Tags: node.js

Не могу разобраться почему не переключаются версии node.js, поможете советом в чём может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился простой перeустановкой пакета NVM.